# Why does 2/5 evaluate to 0 and not 0.4

Tags: python

It seems to be rounding automatically and I don't know how to turn it off. Thanks!

I'm writing code in inline script in open sesame, though the same thing happens in PyCharm. It doesn't happen in other editors though.

Comment: Integer division. Try `2/5.0`

Comment: Integer math. `2.0/5` or `float(2)/5`

Comment: I think it would be useful to mention this is python 2.x. And then switch to python 3!